# animate div larger and smaller Immediately in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to animate div large and smaller in jQuery animate. I wrote this code:

```
$(this).animate({
    opacity: 0,
    top: "-=100",
    width: "38px",
    height: "32px"
}, 1500, function () {
    $this.remove()
})
```

With this code the large div does not get smaller. How I can edit this code for first making it larger div and then smaller immediately? If it possible do this job in CSS3, please help do it in CSS3.

Thank you.

Comment: This might help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes

Comment: @techfoobar very thank's for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With CSS3 animation and `transform: scale();` you can do it :

```
@-webkit-keyframes grow
{
    0%{-webkit-transform:scale(1);}
    50%{-webkit-transform:scale(2);}
    100%{-webkit-transform:scale(1);}
}
@-moz-keyframes grow
{
    0%{-moz-transform:scale(1);}
    50%{-moz-transform:scale(2);}
    100%{-moz-transform:scale(1);}
}
@-ms-keyframes grow
{
    0%{-ms-transform:scale(1);}
    50%{-ms-transform:scale(2);}
    100%{-ms-transform:scale(1);}
}
#spin{
    position:absolute;
    top:10%;
    left:10%;
    -webkit-animation-name: grow;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-animation-name: grow;
    -moz-animation-duration: 3s;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -ms-animation-name: grow;
    -ms-animation-duration: 3s;
    -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e2tt2mao/175/)